# permission denied when running android studio using ./studio.sh or any bash script

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions, permission-denied

I just removed Ubuntu 16 and installed Ubuntu 14 when trying to run bash scripts I get:

```
bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied
```

These are the permissions:

`-rw------- 1 chucky chucky 6917 Mar  3 14:55 studio.sh`

when I try to change the permission to:

```
chmod 777 studio.sh
```

nothing changes.  Tried to change the group permission using GUI it back to None:

[image: Can't change from GUI]

Edit :
The partition which has the problem is NTFS

Comment: Could you show us the mount details? You may have the partition mounted readonly. Also, chmod yields no errors? Try "lsattr" as well.

Comment: how to show th mount details ?
no errors happen 
@barrycarter

Comment: Oh, just type "mount" to see all mounted filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I couldn't change any permissions on NTFS partition from linux
i just move my files to ext4 partition and everything worked fine